# Highchart value series mapping

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

I have a problem with inserting data into highchart I try to customize example from http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo
But my chart doesn't show any information, I looked at the example data, and it is in the same format as my data:

Here is my code in c#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    ...
    var view= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dictionary.dicValues.Select(x => new object[] {x.Key, x.Value}));
    view= Regex.Replace(view, @"\""\\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\\/\""", "$1");
    view= view.Replace(@"[", "").Replace(@"]", "");
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
        {
            view
        },
        ContentType = null,
        ContentEncoding = null,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Here is my js code for creating highchart:

```
$(elem).highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: "title"
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'double',
    },

    series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: data.view,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
    }]
});
```

And here is my data which I pass to the view:

"1421751600000,4.9928500000000007,1421755200000,13.314966666666665,1421758800000,8.316766666666668,1421845200000,14.738,1421848800000,7.9762000000000013"

or if I didn't erase the parentheses:

"[[1421751600000,4.9928500000000007],[1421755200000,13.314966666666665],[1421758800000,8.316766666666668],[1421845200000,14.738],[1421848800000,7.9762000000000013]]"

If someone could help me, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Why are you erasing the parentheses in the first place? It's not valid JSON without them? What does `data.view` actually look like *in the browser*? Is it seeing it as an array? Or just a string?

Comment: @MattBurland at the end of my question I paste the result from 'data.view' with removing parentheses and without removing parentheses

Comment: Is that a string? If you do `typeof data.view` what do you get? I suspect it's being interpreted as a string because for some reason you setting `ContentType` to `null`.

Comment: @MattBurland yes it is, so I should change contenttype to text/json?

Comment: And for that matter, why is your method `GetData` marked with `HttpPost`?

Comment: I assume that's probably the default for `JsonResult`. I wouldn't explicitly set it to anything. I'm not even sure you need to serialize your object yourself, I think it will do it automatically if you set `Data` to an object.

Comment: I'd try just `return new JsonResult() { Data = dictionary.dicValues.Select(x => new object[] {x.Key, x.Value}) };` and see what happens.

Comment: I try it a seconds before You add this comment and it works perfectly for me! Thank You very much. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it as an correct answer to my problem :)

Comment: Your welcome. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply this to:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    return new JsonResult() 
    { 
        Data = dictionary.dicValues.Select(x => new object[] {x.Key, x.Value})
    };
}
```

The defaults for `JsonResult` should give you the correct settings for `ContentType` and it should automatically use the default serializer to serialize your object to a correct JSON string (unless you need some custom serialization).